# Le verbe « obvier » s'emploie-t-il indifféremment de la valeur (fâcheuse) de son complément ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, verbes

Des *lacunes* peuvent-elles « ne pas [obvier](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/obvier) de manière [dirimante](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9DVvHJ0ZEZaQ.html) à des objectifs » (alors que l'on vient de parler de la réalisation de ces objectifs) ? Le TLFi donne comme sens du verbe obvier « parer à une éventualité ou à un fait fâcheux » et note les syntagmes *obvier à un danger, à des difficultés, à un état de choses, à un inconvénient; obvier en partie/largement à qqc*. C'est soit *faire obstacle à un évènement fâcheux*, soit *prendre les précautions nécessaires pour éviter sa survenue* ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/obvier)). Ici on pourrait interpréter la manière comme étant « fâcheuse », voire le sujet (*des lacunes*).

Le verbe s'emploie-t-il indépendamment de la sémantique du complément, un peu comme *empêcher* ; s'agit-il d'une extension de sens ? Est-ce la négation du verbe qui autoriserait un tel emploi ?

Answer (score 1):

"Le verbe s'emploie-t-il indépendamment de la sémantique du complément, un peu comme empêcher ; s'agit-il d'une extension de sens ?"
=> Non. Je n'ai pas d'exemple ancien ou probant en tête d'obvier, employé dans un sens laudatif.

"Est-ce la négation du verbe qui autoriserait un tel emploi ?"
=> Je ne pense pas qu'elle l'autorise, je pense qu'elle l'explique au moins en partie, chez quelqu'un qui se trouvait bien content de ranger "obvier" et "dirimant" dans la même phrase (sans doute un journaliste, un thésard, ou un consultant qui rendait un powerpoint).